# Override Nebula Grid Selected Row Highlighting

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nebula

**Why I want this:**

I have a row selection set up where the user can select a row and then from a separate view, set some options about the row, these options change the colour of the row, but the users cannot see the change taking place becasue the row is highlighted in blue.

I'd like a decent way to show the row is highlighted without the background colour being completely over-ridden, maybe just darkening the colour or with a thick outline that still shows the middle.

**What I've tried:**

I've search through the provided methods but nothing seems to be there to do anything with the highlight behaviour.

Cheers,

Glen x

Comment: Just un-select the row. I suggest you don't fiddle with row selection coloring like that (because, for example, Windows 8 selections look reaaaally different). But if you insist, you could use a custom selection coloring provider. Can't remember the name, but I'll get back to you when I find it.

Comment: I need it to be selected as it links to another view, but I will give it a go and see how it feels

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891025/selection-and-hover-overrides-cell-background-color-in-an-swt-table-component