# How to create custom list widget?

Tags: java, widget, swt

I want to create custom widget, resembling MS File Explorer thumbnail file view or similar.

The questions are:

1) Should I use/extend `Item` class? It is not prohibited to extend this class, but simultaneously it is said, that custom `SWT` widgets are made either of `Composite` or `Canvas`. If I want to put image above it's caption, then I probably am to use `Composite` with table layout. This way I will be unable to extend `Item`. If I extend `Item` somehow, then when to decide, how to draw it?

2) Should I implement all input handlers? I.e. so that selection can be moved by keyboard and mouse, multiple selection with `Ctrl` etc. There is too many code. Can I reuse some premade code for this?

Comment: Can't you use TableViewer without column headers? It allows to use StyledCellLabelProvider, which is helpful to style rows. Also it would be easy to just create image + text appearance in the viewer row.

Comment: How to implement selected state for images this way? Image should be highlighted.

Comment: You can override paint method. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891025/selection-and-hover-overrides-cell-background-color-in-an-swt-table-component